# linguex [judgment symbol]

Tags: horizontal-alignment, formatting, linguistics, linguex

I was wondering how to specify other judgment symbols besides  *, ?, %, and # under \usepackage{linguex}.

```
\ex. \a. *This is ungrammatical.
     \b. $\checkmark$This is grammatical.
     \c. (*)This varies.
```

If we have this, the judgment symbols in (b) and (c) would be treated as part of the sentence; they aren't lined out properly.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding a different judgement symbols to an example can be done by making a macro identical to the one used to place the existing judgement markers in `linguex`:

```
\newcommand{\jdg}[1]{\makebox[0pt][r]{\normalfont#1\ignorespaces}}
```

This allows you to use anything as a judgement marker.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{linguex}

\newcommand{\jdg}[1]{\makebox[0pt][r]{\normalfont#1\ignorespaces}}

\begin{document}
\ex. \a. *This is ungrammatical.
     \b. \jdg{$\checkmark$}This is grammatical.
     \c. \jdg{(*)}This varies.

\end{document}
```

[image: output of first example]

However, as you can see if you use more than one character, as in your '(*)' example,  the spacing will look bad. (BTW, it's not clear to me that this is a linguistically sensible judgement marker at all. What would it mean?  For dialectal variation it's normal to use '%' not '(*)'. )

If you do need to use more than one symbol, then you need to increase the size of the box. To make sure that the markers defined with `\jdg` line up with the automatic ones, you will either need to change the default judgement marker box too, as in the next example or use `\jdg` for all judgements in an example set, in which case, no redefinition is required.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{linguex}

\newcommand{\jdg}[1]{\makebox[.4em][r]{\normalfont#1\ignorespaces}}%
% If you change the width of the box above
%  you need to match the width of the automatic markers:
\renewcommand{\printGramm}{\makebox[.4em][r]{\normalfont\the\CollectTokens}\ignorespaces}
% Since this will make all markers have a larger space,
% alternatively you can use `\jdg` for all markers and
% leave the automatic ones as they are.
\begin{document}
\ex. \a. *This is ungrammatical.
     \b. \jdg{$\checkmark$}This is grammatical.
     \c. \jdg{(*)}This varies.

\end{document}
```

[image: output of second example]